# Mapping dynamic component against non-friendly datatable structure?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, dynamic, fluent-nhibernate

I have a datatable with the following structure:

```
MyTable
-------------------------------------
rule_name      char(20)     PK
value_type     char(20)     PK
value          varchar(50)  not null
dt_last_update datetime     not null
```

Among the data represented in this table, I have a `rule_name` of interest:

```
MailboxSC
```

With which I have two distinct properties or call it `value_type`:

```
numberOfEmails
dateTimeReceived
```

Over which I have no control nor any power.

Using [**DynamicObject**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject(v=vs.110).aspx), I have followed what I could from Ayende Rahien:

[**Support dynamic fields with NHibernate and .NET 4.0**](http://ayende.com/blog/4776/support-dynamic-fields-with-nhibernate-and-net-4-0)

So now, my model.

**EmailIndicator**

```
public class EmailIndicator {
    public EmailIndicator(HashtableDynamicObject hastableDynamicObject) {
        this.hashtableDynamicObject = hashtableDynamicObject;
    }

    public virtual dynamic Attributes { get { return hashtableDynamicObject; } }

    private readonly HashtableDynamicObject hashtableDynamicObject;
}
```

**HashtableDynamicObject**

```
public class HashtableDynamicObject : DynamicObject {
    public HashtableDynamicObject(IDictionary dictionary) {
        this.dictionary = dictionary;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder
        , object[] indexes
        , out object result) {
        result = dictionary[binder.Name];
        return dictionary.Contains(binder.Name);
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder
        , object[] indexes
        , object value) {
        dictionary[binder.Name] = value;
        return dictionary.Contains(binder.Name);
    }

    public override bool TryGetIndex(GetIndexBinder binder
        , object[] indexes
        , out object result) {
        result = dictionary[indexes[0]];
        return dictionary.Contains(indexes[0]);
    }

    public override bool TrySetIndex(SetIndexBinder binder
        , object[] indexes
        , object value) {
        dictionary[indexes[0]] = value;
        return dictionary.Contains(indexes[0]);
    }

    private readonly IDictionary dictionary;
}
```

Now, I'd like to map dynamic properties to each row of `rule_name` `MailboxSC` so that:

```
declare @emailCount             int
declare @oldestDateTimeReceived datetime

select (
        select valeur 
            from bqt001_pilotage_indicateurs 
            where nom_regle like 'boiteCourrielSC'
                and type_valeur like 'nombreCourriels'
      ) as emailCount
      , (
        select valeur as olsdestDateTimeReceived
            from bqt001_pilotage_indicateurs
            where nom_regle like 'boiteCourrielSC'
                and type_valeur like 'dateHeurePlusVieux'
      ) as oldestDateTimeReceived
    into @emailCount
        , @oldestDateTimeReceived
```

So I get my required values, the number of emails and the oldest date/time received.

How to map it using either classic NHibernate XML mapping or Fluent NHibernate?

Linked Ayende Rahien's article provides with a first approach:

```
<class name="Customer"
       table="Customers">

    <id name="Id">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />

    <join table="Customers_Extensions" optional="false">
        <key column="CustomerId"/>
        <dynamic-component name="Attributes" access="field.lowercase">
            <property name="EyeColor" type="System.String"/>
        </dynamic-component>
    </join>
</class>
```

So my guess would be:

```
<class name="EmailIndicatorModel">
    <join table="MyTable" optional="false">
        <dynamic-component name="Attributes" access="field.lowercase">
            <property name="EmailCount" type="System.Int32" />
            <property name="OldestDateTimeReceived" type="System.DateTime" />
        <dynamic-component>
    </join>
</class>
```

And then again, this doesn't allow me to mention the discriminator columns `rule_name` and `value_type` for each of the properties.

Am I condemned to use old-style ADO.NET?

Here are some interesting articles regarding what interests me:

- [**dynamic-component fluent automapping**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834085/dynamic-component-fluent-automapping)
- [**Mapping-by-Code - dynamic component**](http://notherdev.blogspot.ca/2012/01/mapping-by-code-dynamic-component.html)
- [**NHibernate mapping class properties to Rows not Columns**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436125/nhibernate-mapping-class-properties-to-rows-not-columns) (This article led me to Ayende Rahien's article)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to put together possibilities we have for dynamic mapping with NHibernate:

#### [NHibernate Dynamic mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16692541/1679310)

I personally do use and profit a lot from `<dynamic-component>`, but as explained in the resource above, that requires different structure.

#### I. `IDictionary`

So firstly a very usual/standard table for a *Customer*:

```
// [Customer] table with key Customer_ID
Customer_ID, Name, Code,...
          1,  Abc,  xxx,.. 
          2,  Def,  yyy,..
```

Key column `Customer_ID`, and columns describing Customer. Now, if we would like to use `IDictionary` *(or C# dynamic object)* and `<dynamic-component>` to extend the *Customer*, we need table like this:

```
// [CustomerAttributes] - with a key referencing Customer table via Customer_ID
Customer_ID, Attribute1, Attribute2, Attribute3, ...
          1,        123, 2014-01-01,      FALSE, ...
          2,        456, 2015-01-01,       TRUE, ...
```

And this is candidate for

```
<join table="CustomerAttributes" optional="false">
    <key column="Customer_ID"/>
    <dynamic-component name="Attributes">
        <property name="Prop1" column="Attribute1" type="int"/>
        <property name="Prop2" column="Attribute2" type="DateTime"/>
        <property name="Prop3" column="Attribute3" type="bool"/>
    </dynamic-component>
</join>
```

Advantage? we can use ORDER BY. In fact, we can use anything *(SELECT - Projections - [see this custom `ResultTransformer` working with `<dynamic-component>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24248309/1679310), WHERE...)*

BUT there must be standard table, where properties *(keys of `IDictionary`)* are represented by columns.

#### `IDictionary<T,U>`

In case of a Table mentioned above in the question

```
MyTable
-------------------------------------
rule_name      char(20)     PK
value_type     char(20)     PK
value          varchar(50)  not null
dt_last_update datetime     not null
```

We would need `IDictinary<T, U>` and that is mapped with a **`<map>`**:

```
<map name="Attributes" table="MyTable" >
    <key column="rule_name"/>
     <index-many-to-many column="value_type" class="ValueType"/>
     <element column="value" type="string"/>
</map>
```

In this case, we are mapping `ROWS` not columns. This approach is not supporting ORDER BY, nor SELECT (projections)...

SUMMARY: Table, which 1) has values related to our parent table in rows, 2) discriminated by some column is candidate for `<map>`